# Logging which template is being loaded in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Lets say I haven't defined any method for a particular action in the rails Controller (like for /users there is no method, and it will directly load up the template). Is there a way I can modify the Logger (I'm using ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger) to emit a log whenever a template is loaded?

EDIT: The reason why I ask this is that I am refactoring the code and an exception is being raised from the template code. Due to that there is no stack trace available and I am not able to figure out where exactly the error is being raised from (more importantly, I don't know which template is being loaded).

EDIT2:

```
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter.rb:69:in `tableized_conditions'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `inject'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter.rb:67:in `each'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter.rb:67:in `inject'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter.rb:67:in `tableized_conditions'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter.rb:57:in `conditions'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter.rb:94:in `database_records'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/model_additions.rb:23:in `accessible_by'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:81:in `load_collection'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:34:in `load_resource'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `send'
cancan (1.6.8) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `_callback_before_1418'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `_run__482750358__process_action__686174538__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `send'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `action'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
sass (3.2.1) lib/sass/./sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.6) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `send'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `handle_spawn_application'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rack_application'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rack_application'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
/var/lib/passenger-standalone/3.0.17-x86-ruby1.8.7-linux-gcc4.4.6-1002/support/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

Comment: Why is there no stack trace available???

Comment: My bad. I meant to say that the no stack trace is available from my application. I have added the framework stack trace that was thrown.

Comment: Looks like there is a version mismatch, cancan 1.6.8 is looking for a method that doesn't exist,  check to see if you need to upgrade cancan for the version of rails you are running.

Comment: I'm using the latest cancan version.

Comment: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/246